# I couldn't find that what is $M_n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{n}\right)$  and that $|sin(x)|\leq|x|$

a) Use the Weierstrass M-test and Term-by-term Continuity Theorem to show that $ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{n}\right)$ is continuous on any interval  $[-a,a]$

b) Use the Weierstrass M-test and Term-by-term Differentiability Theorem to show that $ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{n}\right)$ is differentiable on any interval $[-a,a]$

c) Is it true that $f ( x )$  is continuous and differentiable on all of $ \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is not really nice to delete your post text since someone has put effort to answer it. Very disrespectful.

Answer (score 1):

Denoting $f_n(x) = \dfrac1n\sin\left(\dfrac{x^2}{n}\right),$ we have $$|f_n(x)| \le \left|\dfrac1n\sin\left(\dfrac{x^2}{n}\right)\right| \le \dfrac{x^2}{n^2} \le \dfrac{a^2}{n^2}.$$
Note that $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. Can you complete it now? (Take $M_n = a^2/n^2$.)